# Persistence context Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

I am wondering what the correct solution to this situation is. The method is running in a transaction. I a remove the first line of this method I will get detached entity passed to persist exception. I understand the problem. The Company is not in the persistence context. 
Is the code below the only solution? Is it better way?

```
@Override
public void delete(Company company) {
    company = companyDao.get(company.getId(), CompanyLoadParameter.LOAD_LANGUAGES);
    companyDao.delete(company);
}
```

Comment: To understand the question, you wish to delete a specific Company entity from the database, but would prefer not to perform the SELECT first ?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to do the same without first fetching the object from the DB.company = companyDao.get(company.getId(), CompanyLoadParameter.LOAD_LANGUAGES);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Session#createQuery("DELETE FROM " + Company.class.getName() +
    " WHERE " + Company.K_id "=?")
    .addParameter(0, CompanyLoadParameter.LOAD_LANGUAGES)
    .executeUpdate();
```

Where Company.K_id is the Java property name (as a string) for the Primary Key.

```
public static final String K_id = "id";
```

I do things this way as the HQL can be refactored using standard IDE tooling and probably continue the work afterwards.

URL on HQL https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: Ok so HQL is the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **this is the correct way** to remove single entity and for my information, there is no better way.

If you have problems with eager fetching, then you should rethink your configuration for JPA entities.

---

There other way is using **HQL DELETE** query, but this has an [issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-368). Delete operation does not cascade to associated collections. It is risky and ugly.

In **JPA 2.1** they mention bulk DELETE query, but they do not mention anything about single entity removal using DELETE query, I think there must be a reason.